# Regular Exp - Add text to first and last of every row

Tags: regex

I have a question regarding to the regular expression. This should be easy and quick.  I am using Notepad ++ and using Find/Replace option as regular exp.  Someone helped before to add "quotation" at beginning and add "line break" at the end of the every line.

In the Find What box:

```
(.*)
```

In Replace With box:

```
"\1 " & vbcrlf & _
```

I understand the \1 means first occurrence, but I couldn't figure out how it knows to add "& vbcrlf & _" at the end of the line?  Please explain the "(.*)" means and the ("\1 " & vbcrlf & _) means.

Thank you,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look like you are trying to convert a plain-text file to VB's string literal.

`(.*)`: `.` matches any character. `*` mean matches zero or more times. `()` means capture the match. So `(.*)` means "match every character on the line and put them into a capture group".

`"\1 " & vbcrlf & _`: `\1` means the first capture group. Due to your search expression, this capture group is the whole line. The others are literal characters. So effectively you putting the whole line in quote and add `& vbcrlf & _` to the end of each line.

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation.